# macos listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

Tags: macos, apache, docker-compose

I'm getting:

```
listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
```

But I have killed all those httpd daemons:

[image]

Why is keep saying that the address already in use?

Comment: Try to find something in `netstat -tulpn`. Also the cooldown of address binding in unix is around few minutes, maybe you need to wait some time

Comment: Why was httpd running in the first place, and is it set to auto-restart (e.g. as a LaunchDaemon or something similar)?

Comment: You may need to give some details of Dockerfile (and/or docker-compose.yml) so that others can see where the problem is.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/text when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I had to start Apache daemon for some project

Comment: @pmiranda How is the Apache daemon started? Depending on how it's set up, it's probably auto-restarting, so killing it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically when apache is running in the background. You can kill it using this command in your linux machine.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```